# Raspberry Pi Google Assistant integration with Sonoff Smart WiFi Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I recently set up Google Assistant on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+.  It works really well and is pretty cool.  I've been really wanting to get into DIY home automation and I would like to pick up some sort of smart WiFi switch that my Assistant can control.

I recently spotted [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRCH67wfwNE) which shows a $5 smart WiFi switch called the Sonoff Smart WiFi switch, which seems to work very well.

How would I add the switches to my Assistant, given that it doesn't have an app as far as I know?
Does one simply pair the switch to your Google Account?

Does anyone have experience working with this device and the Raspberry Pi 3 powered Google Assistant?

I want to know for sure before I bite the bullet and buy a few.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this from google assistant on mobile phone, the process remains same.
You can install ewelink on phone connect the devices and make it functional.

After that go to:-
-> Settings,
-> Home devices,
-> ewelink userid/password
and it will work for you it is working from my mobile phone.